# Python subprocess call with a filename containing ampersands

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, escaping, subprocess

I know there is plenty about this already on S/O but I'm at a loss.  This is the minimum source set to reproduce the issue:

**File test.py**

```
from subprocess import call

Filename1     = "A & B.txt"
Filename2     = "A&B.txt"
Archivename1  = "A & B.7z"
Archivename2  = "A&B.7z"

ShellArgs     = ["7zip.bat", "a", Archivename1, Filename1]
call (ShellArgs, shell = False)

ShellArgs     = ["7zip.bat", "a", Archivename2, Filename2]
call (ShellArgs, shell = False)
```

**File 7Zip.bat**

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" %*
```

`A&B.txt` and `A & B.txt` can be any existing files.  If you are going to try to reproduce the problem I recommend using an empty folder, as the erroneous behaviour causes 7-Zip to try to create an archive of the entire folder's contents.

The issue I have is that the first call works, the second doesn't, and I believe the reason is that Python sees that the argument `A & B.txt` contains spaces, so it double quotes the argument.  The second fails as `A&B.txt` contains no spaces, so it doesn't supply the quotes.  Windows therefore sees the command line

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a A&B.7z A&B.txt
```

which it interprets as 3 chained commands - i.e.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a A
B.7z A
B.txt
```

Unfortunately, the first one is interpreted by 7Zip as "name the archive `A.7z` and put everything you can find in it" (I left it running overnight and came to work to find a 35 Gb file in one of the folders the program traversed).

How can I get around this failure to quote the arguments when the filename has no spaces?  I tried adding them myself, but they (I'm not actually sure who "they" are) helpfully escaped the double quotes -i.e. turned the `"`'s into `\"`'s. I guess other special characters might also cause similar issues - I haven't tried.

Comment: Python passes the arguments list directly to [`CreateProcessW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), there's no quoting involved. Can you call `C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe` directly without using the batch file?

Comment: Many thanks for replying.  I tried that, and yes, it works!  The reason I use the helper batch file for `7-zip.exe` is so that I don't have to edit the `PATH` environment variable every time I add another tool (the helper batch files all live in one folder that is on the path), so I'm reasonably keen to keep it.  Do we conclude that the issue is happening when the helper batch file calls the 7zip exe?  I might do some more experiments - maybe the judicious use of `%~1` etc is the answer.

Comment: I don't know much about Windows internals but this sounds a lot like a use case for [symlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753194(v=ws.10)).

Answer (score 0):

Shy of a bug in Python's Windows `subprocess` module, I think `subprocess.call` is working correctly.  Proof:

```
$ cat ./argtester.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < argc ) {
        printf("ARG %d: %s\n", i+1, argv[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, it spews out each argument passed to it, one per line.  Hopefully we don't pass it any arguments with embedded newlines ... (we don't here).

```
$ cat test.py
from subprocess import call

Filename1     = "A & B.txt"
Filename2     = "A&B.txt"
Archivename1  = "A & B.7z"
Archivename2  = "A&B.7z"

ShellArgs     = ["./argtester", "a", Archivename1, Filename1]
call (ShellArgs, shell = False)

ShellArgs     = ["./argtester", "a", Archivename2, Filename2]
call (ShellArgs, shell = False)
```

And your program, but changing `7zip.exe` to `./argtester`.  Now, compile the argtester:

```
$ gcc -o argtester argtester.c
```

And see what happens:

```
$ python2.7 test.py
ARG 1: ./argtester
ARG 2: a
ARG 3: A & B.7z
ARG 4: A & B.txt
ARG 1: ./argtester
ARG 2: a
ARG 3: A&B.7z
ARG 4: A&B.txt
```

Which is exactly what I would expect, given the arguments.  So, my hunch is the error is either with `7z.exe` or with `7zip.bat`.  Under the principle of "my code is the most likely culprit", I'm guessing `7zip.bat`:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" %*
```

That `%*` looks awfully suspicious.  I don't speak MS command interpreter, but in *nix land/Bash, there are a number of methods of quoting.  To do something similar in Bash land, I would do:

```
/path/to/my/7z "$@"
```

The `"$@"` expands to all arguments, and -- crucially -- also quotes each one, before passing it along to `7z`.  Were I do use `$@` (note the lack of quotes), then I would have the same error in *nix land as you are having in MS land.

Perhaps take a look at the Batch syntax?  Or eschew the batch file altogether and give the complete path to `7zip.exe`?

Comment: Yep, I think you are onto something, also see the comment from @Blender and my reply above.

Comment: @rossmcm yep; the only question is how you plan to fix it.  I suspect Batch files have something similar to `"$@"`.  Where would you find the documentation on that?

Comment: I tried `"%*"` and it put the quotes around the whole of the command tail - i.e. it just rendered them verbatim.